# What is the proper (handwritten) notation for the complex conjugate of a vector?

Tags: notation

Let us say that we have a vector $\vec{v} = \langle 1 + i, i \rangle$. As far as I am aware, using the arrow above the vector as done above is how vectors are generally denoted in writing and also in LaTeX (as it corresponds to the `\vec` command). Textbooks, however, often use a bolded letter, e.g. $\mathbf{v}$, to denote vectors.

Let's say that I want to denote the complex conjugate of the vector above. To denote the complex conjugate of an expression, I've seen bars normally being used, e.g. $\bar{z}$ or $\overline{a + bi}$.

How would I write the complex conjugate of vector $\vec{v}$? In handwriting, I feel like I should simply put a bar over the vector, like $\overline{\vec{v}}$, but this does not looks very nice and seems to hinder communication. I assume I could also write $\overline{\langle 1 + i, i \rangle}$, but I'm looking for a way to denote the conjugate of the vector letter itself. Textbooks I understand probably can get away with writing $\bar{\mathbf{v}}$.

So what is the "proper" way to denote the complex conjugate of some vector in handwriting?

Comment: Most math authors don't put arrows over vectors. So then if $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb C^n$, you could use the notation $\bar x$ for the componentwise complex conjugate of $x$.

Comment: @littleO I think that's about as close to an answer as OP can expect. Perhaps promote your comment to a full answer?

Comment: If you always write arrows over your vectors and conjugating a vector is not a surprise (because it’s mentioned in the surrounding text or a natural thing to do in the specific situation), I don’t think the arrow plus overbar will be confusing. I would make sure that the overbar is longer than the arrow (to “cover” it) but then you’re fine. (It still doesn’t look nice, though.)